# Can only get one result in foreach loop

Tags: php, loops

So I'm trying to get all my emails and email them something. So this is what I'm doing

```
<?php

include_once 'classes/db.php';

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT email FROM users");
$stmt->execute();

$call = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($call as $key){
    echo $key;
}
?>
```

I have two emails in `users`. But all I get is one returned.... Any ideas?

Comment: A good idea in general is to read the manual whenever you get unexpected results from code that looks legit. "PDOStatement::fetch — Fetches the next row from a result set" is the one-line description and it immediately solves the mystery.

Answer (score 1):

[`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) retrieves 1 row and moves the cursor to the next row

```
while($call = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    foreach($call as $key){
        echo $key;
    }
}
```